# How can I get some of a posts meta data whilst it is still inserting?

Tags: custom-post-types, actions, wp-insert-post, post-meta

I'm trying to make a function where a child post of a certain post type inherits the same title and slug as its parent. I'm using WP Types to define my post types and their relationships. But I'm having trouble with the below code:

```
function copy_parent_post_title( $post_id ) {

    $new_post = get_post($post_id);

    if($new_post->post_type == 'carnews-adverts') {

        $parent_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wpcf_belongs_carnews_id', true );
        $parent_title = get_the_title($parent_id);
        $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($parent_title);

        $post_update = array(
            'ID'           => $post_id,
            'post_title' => $parent_title,
            'post_name' => $post_slug
        );

        remove_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'copy_parent_post_title' );
        wp_update_post( $post_update );
        add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'copy_parent_post_title' );

    }

}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'copy_parent_post_title' );
```

The problem is this line:

```
$parent_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wpcf_belongs_carnews_id', true );
```

I presume it is because at this point the post's meta data hasn't been inserted into the database yet? If so how can I achieve what I want by accessing the get_post_meta upon inserting a post?

Thanks

Comment: `wp_insert_post` [runs very late](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L2962). I'd expect this to work but there may be something peculiar about that plugin. What have you done to debug this? Exactly what is happening when you run the code?

Comment: Please ___do not___ duplicate questions: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131042/problem-with-get-post-meta-using-post-id-in-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can move all the logic to `added_post_meta` & `'updated_postmeta'` hooks.

```
add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'update_carnews_adverts_aprent', 10, 4 );
add_action( 'updated_postmeta', 'update_carnews_adverts_aprent', 10, 4 );

function( $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
  if ( $meta_key !== '_wpcf_belongs_carnews_id' || ! is_numeric($meta_value) ) return;
  $post = get_post( $object_id );
  if ( $post instanceof WP_Post && $post->post_type == 'carnews-adverts' ) {
    $parent = get_post( $meta_value );
    if ($post->post_title !== $parent->post_title || $post->post_name !== $parent->post_name) {
       $post_update = array(
          'ID'         => $post->ID,
          'post_title' => $parent->post_title,
          'post_name' => $parent->post_name
       );
       wp_update_post( $post_update );
    }
  }
}
```